# Angular cannot get *ngFor data to display filename list

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 8 and on my .ts file I have this data:

```
mydata = [
    {
        "files": [
            "file1.txt",
            "file2.txt",
            "file3.txt"
        ]
    }
];
```

This I want to display the filenames from the data, so this is what I'm trying:

```
<ul *ngFor="let list of mydata">
    <li>{{ list[0].files }}</li>
</ul>
```

I guess, my format is wrong, as it's not displaying anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try learning the Basics of Angular from angular.io. It documented very nicely. Link- https://angular.io/ This will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filenames are in an array contained in an object which again is part of an array. So you might need two loops based on your actual object. Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of mydata">
  <ul *ngFor="let file of data.files">
    <li>{{ file }}</li>
  </ul>
<ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let list of mydata[0].files">{{list}}</li>
</ul>
```